# Equality of Double boundary values

Tags: c#, double

I'm testing boundary values of some functions which accepts Double values as input. The functions are expected to be able to handle any value of Double, however fails to compare the maximum values of Doubles.

I have tried to isolate the issues and found that the equality of large doubles causes my issues. I attempted to alter the maximum value to not be placed tightly to the maximum value, however with no success

```
// Evaluates to true.
var Equal11 = Double.MaxValue - 100d == Double.MaxValue - 200d;
var Equal12 = (Double.MaxValue - 100d).Equals(Double.MaxValue - 200d);

// Evaluates to false.
var Equal21 = 100d == 200d;
var Equal22 = (100d).Equals(200d);
```

I would expect the Equal11 and Equal12 to be false, just as Equal21 and Equal22 are not equal.

I assume that the double somehow rounds its value close to Double.MaxValue, however I do not understand how to work with this.

Comment: Welcome to the fun of floating-point arithmetic. As an approximate rule of thumb, doubles have ~15-17 digits of precision. Anything beyond that, and if you do some arithmetic, the result might not be exact. "100" only has 3 digits, so you're well within the limits. `double.MaxValue` has around 300 digits, so changing the final 3 of those isn't going to have much significance.

Comment: Yes, I suspected this to be the issue; but gives me a lot of troubles when trying to test my method's boundary value with this behavior. How would you come around that with a fair test coverage?

Comment: I think you're probably looking at this the wrong way. If your method is ever given doubles that are that large, then it probably won't function *anyway*, even if you manage to give it the right input. In general, making methods which use floating-point work under any input is very hard, and takes a lot of time. Most people tend to just ignore the issue, and say that the method is only expected to work with "reasonable-sized" inputs (which matches how it will be used in practice), and test those cases.

Comment: If Max Value is 1000 how can (1000-100) equal (1000-200)?

Comment: I see your point @canton7; it makes sense for the general purpose and we have been using this approach until now. Though, this approach tends to me defining the reasonable maximum out of thin air which seems too vague for an overall strategy.

Comment: Yeah it is a bit vague. In practice the actual maximum depends on exactly what operations you're doing on the double, *and in what order*. It depends hugely on the implementation of the function. A better approach IMO is to say "the function must work for *this range* of inputs", and test that range, rather than trying to determine the range it will *actually* work for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Double` is represented by IEEE 754 64-bit binary floating point:

The gap between consecutive floating point numbers increases as the numbers get bigger. Throughout the normal finite range there are 2<sup>52</sup> values in the range [2<sup>n</sup>, 2<sup>n+1</sup>).

`Double.MaxValue` is about 1.7976931348623157e308. The largest representable value strictly less than it is about 1.7976931348623155e308, difference 1.9958403095347198e292. The result of subtracting a [googol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol) from `Double.MaxValue` rounds to `Double.MaxValue`, explaining the lack of any difference between subtracting 100 and subtracting 200.

All integers in the range [-(2<sup>53</sup>),2<sup>53</sup>] are exactly representable. Any pair of distinct integers in that range will compare unequal, explaining 100 not being equal to 200.

I agree with the advice, in comments, to determine the range over which your application needs to work, and testing it for that range, rather than trying to make it work near to the limits of `Double` arithmetic. You will need to deal with the consequences of floating point rounding. Usually, it leads to inequality of values that would be equal in real number arithmetic, but it can also lead to equality where real number arithmetic would result in inequality.